Azure Portal PowerShell Read Global Admins Certificate
I am trying to read global admins out of a portal using PowerShell.
I know I am very close, I can read VMs and other information out.
I connect in with this:
Connect-AzAccount -CertificateThumbprint $certThumbPrint -ApplicationId $applicationID -Tenant $tenantID -ServicePrincipal
# Verify connection
if (-not (Get-AzContext)) {
    Write-Host "Failed to connect to Azure. Please check your credentials and try again." -ForegroundColor Red
    return
}

I read VMs with this:
# Get a list of VMs
$vms = Get-AzVM 

# Display VM information
foreach ($vm in $vms) {
    Write-Host "VM Name: $($vm.Name), Resource Group: $($vm.ResourceGroupName)"
    # Add more details as needed
}


I try to read global admins with this but get unauthorized error:
Connect-MgGraph -ClientId $applicationID -TenantId $tenantID -CertificateThumbprint $certThumbPrint
# Connect-MgGraph -ClientId $appId -TenantId $tenantId -CertificateThumbprint $thumbprint

$adminRole = Get-MgDirectoryRole -Filter "DisplayName eq '$roleName'"

if ($adminRole) {
    $roleMembers = Get-MgDirectoryRoleMember -DirectoryRoleId $adminRole.Id

    if ($roleMembers) {
        $roleMembers | ForEach-Object {
            [PSCustomObject]@{
                DisplayName = $_.AdditionalProperties["displayName"]
                Id          = $_.Id
            }
        } | Format-Table DisplayName, Id
    } else {
        Write-Host "No members found for the role: $roleName"
    }
} else {
    Write-Host "Role '$roleName' not found"
}

Get-MgDirectoryRole_List:
Line |
4 |  $adminRole = Get-MgDirectoryRole -Filter "DisplayName eq '$roleName'"
|  ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
| Insufficient privileges to complete the operation.
Status: 403 (Forbidden)
ErrorCode: Authorization_RequestDenied
Date: 2024-11-06T22:30:03
Headers:
Cache-Control                 : no-cache
Vary                          : Accept-Encoding
Strict-Transport-Security     : max-age=31536000
App registration permissions:

I feel like I'm missing something small and simple here.
UPDATE:
So these are the permissions I add with my code:
$app = Get-AzADApplication  -ApplicationId $sp.AppId
$appObjectId = $app.Id

Write-Host "ApplicationID: $($sp.AppId)" -ForegroundColor Magenta
# Write-Host $appObjectId -ForegroundColor Magenta

# Assign Reader role to the Service Principal under specific subscription
$spId = (Get-AzADServicePrincipal -DisplayName $applicationName).Id
New-AzRoleAssignment -ObjectId $spId `
    -RoleDefinitionName "Reader" `
    -Scope "/"

# Add Microsoft Graph Directory.Read.All permission of Application type
Add-AzADAppPermission -ObjectId $appObjectId `
-ApiId "00000003-0000-0000-c000-000000000000" `
-PermissionId "7ab1d382-f21e-4acd-a863-ba3e13f7da61" `
-Type Role

I go and manually grant admin consent

AFter running Get-MgContext

I see I am missing the scope permissions.
Thank you all.
UPDATE:
Scoped assigned in correct area


CODE:
Connect-MgGraph -ClientId $applicationID -TenantId $tenantID -CertificateThumbprint $certThumbPrint
Get-MgContext 
$roleName = "Global Administrator"

$adminRole = Get-MgDirectoryRole -Filter "DisplayName eq '$roleName'"

if ($adminRole) {
    $roleMembers = Get-MgDirectoryRoleMember -DirectoryRoleId $adminRole.Id

    if ($roleMembers) {
        $roleMembers | ForEach-Object {
            [PSCustomObject]@{
                DisplayName = $_.AdditionalProperties["displayName"]
                Id          = $_.Id
            }
        } | Format-Table DisplayName, Id
    } else {
        Write-Host "No members found for the role: $roleName"
    }
} else {
    Write-Host "Role '$roleName' not found"
}


ERROR:
Get-MgDirectoryRole_List: 
Line |
   7 |  $adminRole = Get-MgDirectoryRole -Filter "DisplayName eq '$roleName'"
     |  ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
     | Insufficient privileges to complete the operation.

Status: 403 (Forbidden)
ErrorCode: Authorization_RequestDenied
Date: 2024-11-11T18:21:55


Could you confirm whether you are able to read other directory data like users. groups etc... by running Microsoft Graph PowerShell script?

check the updated answer and let me know if it works!

same issue. I have the permissions un Configured Permissions I added another one as well screenshot added. Same error  message and when using Get-MgContext no scopes assigned

Could you confirm whether the clientId in Get-MgContext command output is same as your application's app ID where permissions are configured?

Try disconnecting MgGraph by running Disconnect-MgGraph command and connect again

Client ID is the same as applicationID when running Get-MgContext
Running Disconnect-MgGraph then Connect-MgGraph connecting with cert I get the same issue. Get-MgDirectoryRole_List: Insufficient privileges to complete the operation.

Try assigning directory reader or global reader role to service principal under tenant

Well I'm not sure what changed but today I ran the exact same code and it worked. Nothing changed. Just the single Directory.Read.All API Permission, Thank you!

Initially, I created one app registration and uploaded certificate in it like this:

Now, I added Directory.Read.All permission of Application type in it with admin consent as below:

When I ran same script in my environment, I got the response with list of users having "Global Administrator" role successfully as below:
$applicationID = "appId"
$tenantID = "tenantId"
$certThumbPrint = "65876F7BB07xxxxxxxx4848DDE"
$roleName = "Global Administrator"

Connect-MgGraph -ClientId $applicationID -TenantId $tenantID -CertificateThumbprint $certThumbPrint -Scopes "Directory.Read.All"

$adminRole = Get-MgDirectoryRole -Filter "DisplayName eq '$roleName'"

if ($adminRole) {
    $roleMembers = Get-MgDirectoryRoleMember -DirectoryRoleId $adminRole.Id

    if ($roleMembers) {
        $roleMembers | ForEach-Object {
            [PSCustomObject]@{
                DisplayName = $_.AdditionalProperties["displayName"]
                Id          = $_.Id
            }
        } | Format-Table DisplayName, Id
    } else {
        Write-Host "No members found for the role: $roleName"
    }
} else {
    Write-Host "Role '$roleName' not found"
}

Response:

In your case, try running below PowerShell command after connecting to MS Graph and confirm whether it has Directory.Read.All permission in Scopes parameter or not:
Get-MgContext 


If the permission is not present in Scopes parameter, try removing the added permission in app registration and add it again by granting admin consent.
UPDATE:
The added permission won't come in Scopes of Get-MgContext command if it is present under "Other permissions granted" tab in Portal:

You need to move it to Configured permissions of your application by clicking below option:

In Portal, permission should appear under Configured permissions like this:

Now, connect to MS Graph via client certificate authentication again and check Get-MgContext. Now, it should work.

It feels quite weird here, I have copied you code and test, all good.
But my connection using service principal secret here which I think there is no real difference here.
I have the same application permission as you.
Show in application registrations

Show in Enterprise applications


Your code with slight connecting method changed (not impact I think)
$roleName = "Global Administrator"

$ApplicationClientId = 'xxxx'
$ApplicationClientSecret = 'xxxx'
$TenantId = 'xxx' 

$SecureClientSecret = ConvertTo-SecureString -String $ApplicationClientSecret -AsPlainText -Force
$ClientSecretCredential = New-Object -TypeName System.Management.Automation.PSCredential -ArgumentList $ApplicationClientId, $SecureClientSecret

Connect-MgGraph -TenantId $TenantId -ClientSecretCredential $ClientSecretCredential

$adminRole = Get-MgDirectoryRole -Filter "DisplayName eq '$roleName'"

if ($adminRole) {
    $roleMembers = Get-MgDirectoryRoleMember -DirectoryRoleId $adminRole.Id

    if ($roleMembers) {
        $roleMembers | ForEach-Object {
            [PSCustomObject]@{
                DisplayName = $_.AdditionalProperties["displayName"]
                Id          = $_.Id
            }
        } | Format-Table DisplayName, Id
    } else {
        Write-Host "No members found for the role: $roleName"
    }
} else {
    Write-Host "Role '$roleName' not found"
}

My result:

